# How to find out what Jar used in a apk file?

Tags: android, jar, apk

Given a android apk file,is there a simple way to find out what jar used in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as i know it is not possible to find out what **jar-s** were used because when creating an android apk the content of the jars is compiled into the apk.

If the developper of the apk hasn-t used an Obfuscater software you can find out the namespaces and classnames involved in the build using the [apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/). The Namespaces may be a hint which jars were used.